# Autofill sheet 2 with sheet 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill

I have sheet 1 which contains:

I'll just put "Y" as "Passed", the 2nd information of Joan is not yet complete because it's not yet finish.

```
Name | Attendance | Final Grade | Result
Juan |     Y      |      Y      | Passed
Joan |     Y      |             |
```

I create a 2nd sheet with only 1 column saying "Graduates". What I want here now is when the Column Result (D2) on Sheet 1 says that the students Passed. It will fill the Column on Sheet 2 (A2) with the name of the student that passed.

Like this:

```
Graduates |
Juan      |
```

So far, I tried auto-filling the Sheet 2 using Sheet 1 by putting `=Sheet1!D2` on my cell on sheet 2 (A2), but how can I put the data under Column Name (on sheet1) on Column Graduates (on sheet2) if the Person on sheet1 has a value under the column Result?

Comment: Welcome to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I believe you will find that showing some original effort (working or not) will get faster, focussed attention to your question. Edit your question to include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sheet2's A2 use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$9999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+(Sheet1!D$2:D$9999<>"passed")*1E+99, , ), COUNTA(A$1:A1))), "")
```

Fill down for a large number of rows equal to the number of students in sheet1. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Auto-populate sheet2 on conditions]

As soon as Joan has *Passed* put into column D through typing or formula, the results on sheet2 will change to something like:

[image: Auto-populate sheet2 on conditions]

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) shows empty strings (e.g. "") for every cell you filled down that cannot produce a matching value.

Comment: I recommend using the formula that you gave, than mine. Thank you @Jeeped. But what if I add a 2nd column on sheet 2 named "Complete attendance" and If the student is already under the "Graduates" list it will not show the name of the students in "Complete attendance" if he/she is already under the "Graduates" list.

Comment: I'm sorry @spideynok but I'm unclear on that new requirement fits in. You would need to edit your original question again to provide sample data together with expected results. Adding a second condition is not a problem; it is just that I cannot imagine what you propose from your current explanation.

Comment: Wait a sec.. I think I understand. You would want column B AND column D being Y and Passed before they go into the list. What about column C?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jepeped. Uhmm, Because when Column B and C is "Y" the column D will fill with "Passed", On the 2nd sheet. If I will create Column B "Complete Attendance" it will display "Y" on sheet 2 the same on sheet 1(ColumnB Attendance), if the students Y both Column B and C and Passed the Column D. The name will show on Graduates column, also on Complete Attendance column, right? what I want to do is that students who is already in Graduates list, his/her name will not be shown in "Complete Attendance" list.

Comment: Some of your logic seems to contradict itself. If a student needs a Y in both column B and column C to get a *Passed* then making another list for *Complete Attendance* which lists students that need to have their attendance completed would never be part of the *Graduates* column since they would never have a Y in column B. As I've said, sample data together with the expected results is often much better than trying to describe a complex situation.

Comment: Sorry for that, this is an example only. Lets just change the Complete attendance to "For Consideration" and you'll be included on the list if your Attendance is Y. Sorry for complicating things sir @jeeped.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it using this formula in Sheet2

```
=IF((Sheet1!D2="Passed"),Sheet1!A2,"")
```