# Auto remove, if data already exist on other column

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, autofill

I made a sample records of students showing if they're able to graduate based on the exam taken on **Sheet 1**, I just put 1 to mean that they passed that exam and blank if they not. To be under For Consideration you need to pass the Prelim and Midterm Exam. See image.

[image]

Then I made a **2nd Sheet** that will just summarize the name of the students that will Graduate and those students that will under Consideration. See image.

[image]

I'm using this code given by @Jeeped in my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634673/autofill-sheet-2-with-sheet-1/30635596#30635596).

> =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$9999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+(Sheet1!E$2:E$9999<>"Passed")*1E+99, , ), COUNTA(A$1:A1))), "")

You can see the result on the 2nd image, what I want to happen here is that if the student is already listed on Graduates, his/her name will not show under For Consideration. Any suggestion or modification on the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an AND condition that excludes the values *Passed* in Sheet1's column F.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$9999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+((Sheet1!E$2:E$9999<>"Passed")+(Sheet1!F$2:F$9999="Passed"))*1E+99, , ), COUNTA(A$1:A1))), "")
```

This method is based on excluding non-matching results so if we want to keep the entries that have *Passed* in column E, we use `+(Sheet1!E$2:E$9999<>"Passed")` to exclude those that don't. Similarly if you want to exclude the entries that *do* have a *Passed* in column F then add in a `+(Sheet1!F$2:F$9999="Passed")` and bracket the two conditions together.